# use of strcat function

Tags: matlab

I would like to check that I have

```
workingDir = C:\Users\~\Temp\workspace_folder;
 for i=1:2
 % do an action which generates folder C:\Users\~\Temp\workspace_folder_1 first iteration
 % and increment for each iteration
 x = strcat(workingDir,'_',i);
end
```

it gives only

x = C:\Users\~\Temp\workspace_folder_ , why do it doesn't print me the iteration value?
I expected to have

```
C:\Users\~\Temp\workspace_folder_1
C:\Users\~\Temp\workspace_folder_2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert i to string using `int2str`